# EXCEL to VBA code translation

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

To extract the first coefficient of polynom which approximate a function, I use this formula:

```
=INDEX(DROITEREG(B2:B10;A2:A10^{1.2.3});1)
```

But when i want to use it as a VBA code like that :

```
a = INDEX(DROITEREG(B2:B10;A2:A10^{1.2.3});1)
```

I get a syntax error

Can someone help me to resolve this problem? Thank you

Comment: Is that a valid Excel formula? Excel is showing err msg when I enter this.

Comment: `DROITEREG` is the French name for `LINEST`

Answer (score 0):

To use Excel formulas in VBA you must use `Application.WorksheetFunction.<function name>` as follows (if using inside of Excel, the `Application.` can be left out):

```
a = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(DROITEREG(B2:B10;A2:A10^{1.2.3});1)
```

I was unsure how to implement the `DROITEREG` function and left it as is.

[See MSDN for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211481%28v=office.14%29.aspx)